# Converting LC-3 to C

Tags: c, lc3

I'm trying to convert LC-3 statement such as the ADD instruction to C. So far my approach is to read the contents of a file which contains hex values that represent the instructions set. Then convert the hex values to binary and split the bits for the registers, operands and etc. But I'm not sure how to start because I'm very new to C programming language and it is very different from Python. So can anyone suggest how I would write the this C-Programme? Maybe pseudo code?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I would just like to know how to program this? (converting lc-3 add instruction to c?).Sorry very new to this language(Currently reading C Essentials for dummies)

Comment: This site is not very good at answering "i-dont-know-where-to-start" type questions.

Comment: can you define what this means exactly? What do you mean when you say "convert an assembly instruction to C"? C is a higher level language, it has variables but it does not operate on registers that I assume LC-3 has. So, how does the LC-3's `ADD` operation work? what does it add? Does it need a register and a constant?

Comment: It works on both but in my case add will operate only on registers